# How can I lie to the user about the value of a text input using plain old JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

#### The Problem

I am the very definition of evil, and as such, I take great pleasure in lying to my users.

Presently, I am seeking a way to mislead these dumb fools with respect to the content of text input boxes. I want to display a value in the input box, while submitting a different value entirely. Additionally, I'd like to reward those users who are brave enough to inspect the element's value property with an honest response.

Those wily supervillains at Google have already done this internally in their own browser:

http://plnkr.co/edit/lRG9YGJMDVM8NgCOp6NV (view in Chrome. Play with the input values)

Here is the JavaScript:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var date = document.getElementById('date');
  var time = document.getElementById('time');

  var show_date = document.getElementById('show_date');
  var show_time = document.getElementById('show_time');

  var display_real_value = function() {
    show_date.innerHTML = date.value;
    show_time.innerHTML = time.value;
  }

  display_real_value();

  date.addEventListener('change', display_real_value);
  time.addEventListener('change', display_real_value);
  date.addEventListener('keyup', display_real_value);
  time.addEventListener('keyup', display_real_value);
});
```

#### The Details

As you will see in that example, the displayed value is totally detached from what is actually in the value property. I actually need to be able to programmatically modify both.

Finally, I'd like to implement this without jQuery, and without adding any additional DOM elements, nor making any assumptions about the context it will appear in. Limiting support to evergreen browsers is acceptable, though support for older browsers would be nice.

#### The Use Case

Since I'll undoubtedly be told that this is a bad idea or asked what I intend to use this for, I'll answer that now: My intention is to make a polyfill for date and time inputs that work very very similarly to Chrome's implementation, and which can be styled and scripted without the user having to know anything about how the polyfill works.

#### The Best Idea So Far

I suspect I might get somewhere with getters and setters, and storing the actual value on a different property of the object, but I haven't had any luck meeting all of my criteria.

#### Additional Explanation

The reason I don't want to add new, hidden DOM elements is because when the user wants to script the date input they've added, they have to look for the value of the hidden input instead of the one they actually added. I'd like to make this work as transparently as possible so that it as simple as adding the script and forgetting about it.

Here are some bullet points on what I need to do:

- Programmatically update the string displayed in the input. I've been using setRangeText for this.
- Programmatically update the selected portion of the displayed input. I've been using setSelectionRange for this.
- Retrieve the modified value using element.value on the original input element.
- Submit the modified value when the form submits.

Maybe this just isn't possible. That's fine if that is the best answer, but I'm hoping there is something I haven't thought of.

Comment: Why not do it with separate hidden elements? Give the hidden elements the real names, and the visible ones fake names that'll be ignored by the server.

Comment: Wait for it, wait.... what have you tried so far?

Comment: Or if it's part of a form, just a hidden input tag with an id that gets submitted along with the request. You can create such a thing without jquery, obviously, and add it to the DOM inside the form tag. Or you could just parse the visible field itself with a piece of script prior to submission. After submission too, if you're worried about cleaning your input.

Comment: @vector Haven't tried much so far. I tried using a getter and setter to return value from a different property that I added to the element.  That seemed to break the link between what I typed in the input, and what showed up in the value property, but submitting the form sent the display value, and I have no idea how to update the display value programmatically without changing the value property. setRangeText updated the value property, sadly.

Comment: @Pointy I may have to do that. I intend to release this for public consumption, so I have been hoping to avoid changing any markup at all.

Comment: @NickSloan: You wouldn't change the markup. You'd change the DOM structure when your control was applied to the inputs.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Fair point. I misspoke. Either way, if it is at all avoidable, I would prefer not to modify the DOM in any way. That forces the user to have to know something about how my polyfill works. At minimum, they have to inspect a different element for the value when scripting that input. If that's avoidable, I'd love to avoid it.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions for improving this question. Surprised by the crazy amount of down votes.

Comment: @NickSloan: *Anything* you do can easily be reverse-engineered. Modifying the DOM is probably unavoidable, but more to the point, avoiding it is likely to be pointless. Even if you could come up with a really creative CSS hack, it'd still be easily reverse-engineered.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm fine with it being reverse-engineerable. Maybe my jokes about villainy are misleading the discussion. My aim here is to make a polyfill that developers who use it don't have to know anything about. If they dig into it to do weird stuff, that's fine, but they shouldn't have to look at the value property of some hidden element that I add to get the value of the element they originally added to the page. While this needs to work if the input is in a form, it should work just as well outside of a form.

Comment: @NickSloan: Ah, when you said "that forces the user to know how my polyfill works" I thought you meant the *end* user.

Comment: Whatever you do, keep mobile browsers in mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your replies to comments under the question, here's what I think you want to do:

When the programmer using your polyfill applies it to an element, hide that element (e.g., `element.style.display = "none";`) and put your own element(s) in its place to provide your UI. This is fairly standard practice; look at [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/), for instance.

When the user of the page updates the value via your UI, you put the appropriate value in the field you hid.

The programmer using your polyfill doesn't have to know how it works; he/she just reads the value from the original field (again, with code, or by submitting the form the field is in).

There's some knowledge that programmer has to have: He/she has to know that if he/she wants to *set* the value of the field using JavaScript *after* applying your polyfill to the field, he/she should do that through your API, not by setting the value of the field directly. This is because there's no reliable, cross-browser event triggered when JavaScript sets the value of a form field. While you *could* poll, looking for updates, frankly that seems unreasonable. (Although I suppose if you had a list of all of your special inputs in the DOM, and checked the entire list once every 100ms or so, the performance impact would be negligible. But if the programmer is using your polyfill, it shouldn't be a big deal to set values through your API. I suppose you could offer both options.)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. As I said, if there is some magic that can be accomplished to avoid the user having to use my API, I'd prefer that. In my opinion, a polyfill isn't really a polyfill if it requires an API other than what is provided by the browser.

With that said, I'll accept this solution if no one comes up with a better option after a few hours. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @NickSloan: I don't think you'll be able to avoid making them notify you of changes to the value. I don't think even [mutation observers](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/) (the replacement for the flawed old mutation events) give you a way to watch the `value` property (just the `value` attribute, which is different), and of course even if they did, [support is a bit spotty](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver).

Comment: Thanks for the patience and the answer. I've accepted this, though I wish there were a better solution. This would all be irrelevant if browser vendors would get on with date and time input implementations.